# AS3 nested swf doesn't show in html

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm using the following AS3 code to load an external swf (one with dimensions I don't like) into another swf. When I view the loader swf while embedded in a html page nothing is displayed even though the loader swf displays the nested swf without a problem in preview.

```
    package  
    {
        import flash.display.Loader;
        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.net.URLRequest;
        import flash.events.Event;

        public class Main extends MovieClip
        {
            private var swfLoader:Loader;
            public function Main() 
            {
                swfLoader = new Loader();
                swfLoader.load(new URLRequest("nested.swf"));
                swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
            }

            private function loadComplete(e:Event)
            {
                addChild(swfLoader);
            }
        }
    }
```

And here's the HTML I'm using:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="../includes/samplestyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="../Scripts/swfobject_modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript">AC_FL_RunContent = 0;</script>
    <script src="../includes/AC_RunActiveContent.js" language="javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: transparent;">
    <script language="javascript">
        if (AC_FL_RunContent == 0) {
            alert("This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js.");
        } else {
            AC_FL_RunContent(
                'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0',
                'width', '320',
                'height', '240',
                'src', 'includes/loaderSwf',
                'quality', 'high',
                'pluginspage', 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',
                'align', 'middle',
                'play', 'true',
                'loop', 'true',
                'scale', 'showall',
                    'wmode', 'transparent',
                'devicefont', 'false',
                'id', 'includes/loaderSwf',
                'bgcolor', '#ffffff',
                'name', 'includes/loaderSwf',
                'menu', 'true',
                'allowFullScreen', 'false',
                'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
                'movie', '../includes/loaderSwf',
                'salign', ''
                ); //end AC code
        }
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="320" height="240" id="includes/loaderSwf" align="middle">
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
        <param name="movie" value="../includes/loaderSwf.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />   <embed src="../includes/loaderSwf.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="320" height="240" name="includes/loaderSwf" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
        </object>
    </noscript>
    </body>
    </html>
```

If I substitute the name "loaderSwf" with the nested swf name it plays fine. It seems as though the local html page does not like the fact that I'm playing a swf through another swf. Does anybody have any inside on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your loaderSwf and nested.swf is not located in the same place as your html-file. Try doing `swfLoader.load(new URLRequest("includes/nested.swf"));` or `swfLoader.load(new URLRequest("../includes/nested.swf"));`, depending on how your file structure looks.

It might also be useful to display the loading error message that is thrown from the swfLoader.

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I missed that.